# setTimeout does not work when put in sequence

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I think I made a small typo or something like that, because something clearly doesn't work as it should. I want to change the ID's of two different divs, in a sequence.

```
setTimeout(function() {$("#t1").attr('id','t1out')}, 4000)});
setTimeout(function() {$("#t2").attr('id','t1')}, 4500)});
```

Somehow, this manages to mess up the entire javascript, so nothing runs at all.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: You mean, you want to set id of t1 first, then t2?

Comment: why do you want to change the id of an element?

Comment: There's two divs, "t1" and "t2". After 4000 ms, "t1"'s ID will be set to t1out, so a CSS3 animation occurs. 500 ms later, I want "t2" to get ID "t1", so it animates in.

Comment: there are syntactical problems in the script

Comment: Could you tell me what they are? As I've tried to find them, without succes unfortunately.

Comment: @MeesBoeijen see my answer down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntactical problems in the script . There is an extra `}` at the end of each statements.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1')
    $("#t1").attr('id', 't1out')
}, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('2')
    $("#t2").attr('id', 't1')
}, 4500);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PzwGg/)

Comment: That's awesome. I really had no idea. I'm still in a learning process of getting used to javascript. So thanks a lot!:)

Comment: @MeesBoeijen check your browser's console to see any javascript error